# How do I serve a generated file in Django via nginx as download?

Tags: python, django, nginx

I'm trying to serve a generated zip file in my media folder via nginx, but I got the following error: `open() "/etc/nginx/htmltest.zip" failed (2: No such file or directory)`

Somehow nginx is looking for the file in a weirdly malformed "/etc/nginx/html", I don't get why.

I'm using nginx via docker-compose, the code works just fine if I don't use nginx and just run Django in development mode.

```
folder_path = os.path.join(settings.MEDIA_ROOT, str(uuid.uuid4()))
os.mkdir(folder_path)

shutil.make_archive(os.path.join(folder_path, "test"), 'zip', folder_path, "test")

response = download(os.path.join(folder_path, f"{zip_name}.zip"))


def download(path):
    if os.path.exists(path):

        with open(path, 'rb') as f:
            response = HttpResponse(f.read(), content_type="application/zip")
            response['Content-Disposition'] = 'inline;filename=' + os.path.basename(path)
            response['X-Accel-Redirect'] = os.path.basename(path)
            return response

    raise Http404
```

My nginx.conf:

```
upstream django_app {
    server web:8000;
}

server {

    listen 80;

    location / {
        proxy_pass http://django_app;
        proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-For $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
        proxy_set_header Host $host;
        proxy_redirect off;
        client_max_body_size 100M;
    }

    location /static/ {
        alias /code/static/;
    }

    location /media/ {
        alias /code/media/;
    }

}
```

MEDIA_ROOT in settings.py:

```
MEDIA_URL = '/media/'
MEDIA_ROOT = os.path.join(BASE_DIR, 'media')
```

Answer (score 1):

You are using [nginx `X-Accel-Redirect`](https://www.nginx.com/resources/wiki/start/topics/examples/x-accel/) incorrectly.

When using `X-Accel-Redirect` you do not need to read and send the file from Django yourself, nginx will do it for you. That is the whole point of `X-Accel-Redirect`: offloading file sending from the app server to nginx (which is better at it).

So remove the `X-Accel-Redirect` header, then Django will serve the file directly.

If you want to use `X-Accel-Redirect` then you need to setup nginx as described in the documentation (your config is not complete as it is missing the `internal` location) and then give the internal **URL** in the `X-Accel-Redirect` header (you are incorrectly giving a file system path).